# Resize a kernel

Tags: c++, opencv

For learning purposes I am implementing a blur function. I have it working but I want to resize my kernel to achieve a more blurred affect.

If I scale up my kernel will that indeed create a more blurred affect? And how can I resize my kernel?

I have tried to resize the kernel using `resize` but that results in a white image.

```
// create blur kernel
float kdata[] = { 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f,   0.125f, 0.25f, 0.125f, 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f };
Mat kernel(3, 3, CV_32F, kdata);

// resize kernel to 9x9 to create a more blurred effect
resize(kernel, kernel, {9,9});

// output is white, whats going wrong?
filter2D(src, output, -1, kernel);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the coefficients in the kernel must add to 1.0. Your new kernel has 9x as many values, but you didn't scale them. So, as a result your blurring also multiplies intensities by 9.

Comment: @DanMašek I see, thanks that makes sense. Does opencv have a function that will scale kernels? Ie scale the values and the dimensions? Should I just do `kernel *= 3;` after resizing?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Since you know that the sum of all elements must be 1.0, I'd calculate the sum if your resized kernel, and then divide each element by that sum. This is really quite simple to achieve, so I wouldn't expect there to be a specific function to do so.

Comment: This doesn't work if you need negative numbers for stuff like edge detection. The negatives can outweigh the positives and give you a color that is out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going a bit to the basics, a kernel is a matrix that is convoluted with your image.

The operation of convolution picks a pixel in each matrix, overlaps the kernel at the kernel's anchor point (usually the middle), and you sum all the values in the image weighted by the values in the kernel.

For example, imagine you had the kernel:

```
1 0 -1
0 0 0
-1 0 1
```

(only for demonstration purposes - the values are random)

With the anchor point at the center. Then, filter2D would take all the pixels in the image and overlap the kernel. At each pixel, it would add the upper left and the lower right pixels and subtract the upper right and the lower left pixels, as indicated by the weights in the kernel.

Now, to achieve a greater blur, you need to have a bigger kernel. You cannot simply resize the kernel - the resize function is to change the size of the images. For the kernel, you need to compute the values of the bigger kernel - keep in mind that the kernel is a matrix with special values, not an image.

What a kernel for Gaussian blur does is to have the values carefully chosen (according to a Gaussian distribution) such that the center pixel (the initial value) has the biggest contribution to the final pixel, but also the surrounding pixels get added, with lesser and lesser weights. The contribution of the surrounding pixels, their weights, are tuned by the sigma parameter of the Gaussian. This parameter indicates how fast the gaussian's value drop.

In the end, you need to calculate the values for your kernel, considering the sigma and the size of the kernel you want. This is done either manually (pen and paper), or use a calculator such as this one: http://dev.theomader.com/gaussian-kernel-calculator/.

Comment: When you have OpenCV, you might as well use the existing function `getGaussianKernel` rather than working out on paper or some website.

Comment: Indeed, but in the question he was mentioning that is done for learning purposes, so I tried to give some insight in the internals of `getGaussianKernel`

Comment: @Paul92 thanks, does opencv have a function to resize any kernel? Not just a gaussian kernel? For eg `[ 0.1111,0.1111,0.1111, 0.1111,0.1111,0.1111, 0.1111,0.1111,0.1111]`? If I want to scale this 3x3 up to 9x9 I can calculate it manually but if there is an opencv function that would be preferable

Comment: @JakeM there can't be any such function, for the reasons I mentioned. In your example, what you would want to do is to add more 0.1111 around the borders and then scale all the values accordingly, while for a Gaussian kernel you want to recompute all the values to fit the Gaussian distribution - hard for a function to guess. What you can do is to use various tricks to obtain it. For example, you could use cv::Mat::ones(9) / (1/81); to get the 9x9 kernel, or you could use getGaussianKernel to get a Gaussian kernel - very rarely you have to hardcode the values for standard kernels.